# I am installing a wordpress theme in local host of wamp server,but theme is not showing up properly?

Tags: html, wordpress

When I install the theme (themeforest-7789703-medicalpress-health-and-medical-wordpress-theme.zip) it is showing hello world blog, only a banner and color is changed. Remaining everything looks same.
 How to activate theme exactly?

Comment: I am afraid you will get many down-votes for this... Which theme? Did you imported demo content (most modern themes have that feature)?

Comment: When you install a new theme it doesn't always look much different from the default theme. But you can customize it.

Comment: sorry, I just created my account today. I dont know much about this site

Comment: http://inspirythemesdemo.com/medicalpress/documentation/ - here you will find all, and i guess, you are especially interested for this: http://inspirythemesdemo.com/medicalpress/documentation/#auto-import-contents

Comment: hey nevermind, thanks alot...., thats exactly what I needed. as I am begginner. I didnt even know documentation exists.  really thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

go to theme settings. set menu. also you can impoer dummy data from xml provided by theme. hope it helps.